# Change Register Middleware Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, composer-php, middleware

After running `php artisan make:auth`and config all stuff, I wish only logged users may register another users.

Since Laravel provides `Auth::routes()` by default in the `routes\web.php` file, how can I redefine the middlware of `/register`?

Another thing about it is that, if the user is already logged in, he cannot register because the route redirects him to `/home` URI. I wish I could change this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want guest user to be registered you can disable registration for guest by changing `$this->middleware('guest');` to `$this->middleware('auth');` in your app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php 's __construct method.